# A way to put UITextField into UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel, textfield

I am looking for a way to replace certain words in UILabel with UITextFields.
Like on the photo.
[image]
I could arrange them manually, but the problem is that my app includes many tasks, and in each task the UITextFields should be located in different places.
So, it may sound weird, but I am looking for the method that replaces the word in Label with the Textfield. Other solutions won't help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's probably no easy way to do this, and even if there was you probably shouldn't from a UI design point of view. Have a look at this page, particularly the Organization section: https://developer.apple.com/design/tips/